# Error accessing field [private java.lang.String entities.Register.numVocher] by reflection for persistent property [entities.Register#numVocher]

Tags: hibernate, entity

/*The code for Entity Class*/ 
    package entities;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author Ashish
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "register")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Register.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Register r"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Register.findById", query = "SELECT r FROM Register r WHERE r.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Register.findByTxtEmail", query = "SELECT r FROM Register r WHERE r.txtEmail = :txtEmail"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Register.findByTxtName", query = "SELECT r FROM Register r WHERE r.txtName = :txtName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Register.findByTxtPassword", query = "SELECT r FROM Register r WHERE r.txtPassword = :txtPassword"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Register.findByNumPhone", query = "SELECT r FROM Register r WHERE r.numPhone = :numPhone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Register.findByTxtRole", query = "SELECT r FROM Register r WHERE r.txtRole = :txtRole"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Register.findByNumVocher", query = "SELECT r FROM Register r WHERE r.numVocher = :numVocher")})
public class Register implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "txt_email")
    private String txtEmail;
    @Column(name = "txt_name")
    private String txtName;
    @Column(name = "txt_password")
    private String txtPassword;
    @Column(name = "num_phone")
    private String numPhone;
    @Column(name = "txt_role")
    private String txtRole;
    @Column(name = "num_vocher")
    private String numVocher;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "numVoucher")
    private ElectionCard electionCard;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "numVoucher")
    private Address address;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "numVoucher")
    private Passport passport;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "numVoucher")
    private Collection<AdhaarCard> adhaarCardCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "numVoucher")
    private Collection<PanCard> panCardCollection;

    public Register() {
    }

    public Register(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTxtEmail() {
        return txtEmail;
    }

    public void setTxtEmail(String txtEmail) {
        this.txtEmail = txtEmail;
    }

    public String getTxtName() {
        return txtName;
    }

    public void setTxtName(String txtName) {
        this.txtName = txtName;
    }

    public String getTxtPassword() {
        return txtPassword;
    }

    public void setTxtPassword(String txtPassword) {
        this.txtPassword = txtPassword;
    }

    public String getNumPhone() {
        return numPhone;
    }

    public void setNumPhone(String numPhone) {
        this.numPhone = numPhone;
    }

    public String getTxtRole() {
        return txtRole;
    }

    public void setTxtRole(String txtRole) {
        this.txtRole = txtRole;
    }

    public String getNumVocher() {
        return numVocher;
    }

    public void setNumVocher(String numVocher) {
        this.numVocher = numVocher;
    }

    public ElectionCard getElectionCard() {
        return electionCard;
    }

    public void setElectionCard(ElectionCard electionCard) {
        this.electionCard = electionCard;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Passport getPassport() {
        return passport;
    }

    public void setPassport(Passport passport) {
        this.passport = passport;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<AdhaarCard> getAdhaarCardCollection() {
        return adhaarCardCollection;
    }

    public void setAdhaarCardCollection(Collection<AdhaarCard> adhaarCardCollection) {
        this.adhaarCardCollection = adhaarCardCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<PanCard> getPanCardCollection() {
        return panCardCollection;
    }

    public void setPanCardCollection(Collection<PanCard> panCardCollection) {
        this.panCardCollection = panCardCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Register)) {
            return false;
        }
        Register other = (Register) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities.Register[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Full Stack Trace is

> org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error
>   accessing field [private java.lang.String entities.Register.numVocher]
>   by reflection for persistent property [entities.Register#numVocher] :
>   1     at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:43)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:58)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:419)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:242)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.generateHashCode(EntityUniqueKey.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.(EntityUniqueKey.java:48)
>     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:679)
>     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:427)   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:154)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1132)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:992)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)  at
>   controller.ElectionCardUpload.execute(ElectionCardUpload.java:44)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>   Hibernate: select register0_.id as id1_5_, register0_.num_phone as
>   num_phon2_5_, register0_.num_vocher as num_voch3_5_,
>   register0_.txt_email as txt_emai4_5_, register0_.txt_name as
>   txt_name5_5_, register0_.txt_password as txt_pass6_5_,
>   register0_.txt_role as txt_role7_5_ from register register0_ where
>   register0_.num_vocher=?   at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:325)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:325)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field
>   entities.Register.numVocher to java.lang.Integer  at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)  at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
>     ... 96 more

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have `mapped = numVoucher` when the field name is `numVocher` (without the 'u'), make them consistent and try again.

I would suggest you rebuild the project from scratch and revisit the table schema if that doesn't work.